# My Android App is not loading the new url page in webview using intent-filters

Tags: java, android, webview

I am using webview and calling my website to show it in the android app. And I used intent-filters to open the external URLs to redirect and open them in the app instead of web-browser. Everything works fine but the problem is when I click on a URL it opens my app but when I click on another URL it opens the same app but doesn't redirect to the new URL it is showing the old URL page.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="my_website.com"
                        android:path="/app.html" />
                </intent-filter>
```

MainActivity.java

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.loadUrl("my_website");


        Uri intentUri = getIntent().getData(); //get link
        if (intentUri != null) {
            webView.loadUrl(intentUri.toString()); //open it in webView
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Have you logged intenturi and validated it whether its coming correctly?

Comment: Where can I log it? @GowthamKK

Comment: Before checking loading webview, add Log.d("SomeTag",intentUri.toString());

Comment: I did give the Log.d but it is not showing any data @GowthamKK

Comment: Is the webview activity launching correctly?

Comment: Initially it is launching very fine and when first intent url is clciked it is launching the correct page. Then if I am trying to click another url it is opening the app which is in the background but is not redirecting to the new url page, it is shoding the old page only. @GowthamKK